Why does the guilt remain after forgiveness in Exodus 34:7?
In Exodus 7:34, God says He is abounding in goodness and mercy and forgives iniquity and transgression but he doesn't clear the guilt, what does this mean? Does it mean God forgives the individual but punishes the later generations for a sin He already forgave?
Exodus 7:34

[7]keeping mercy for thousands, forgiving iniquity and transgression and sin, by no means clearing the guilty, visiting the iniquity of the fathers upon the children and the children’s children to the third and the fourth generation.”

Refer to the incident where David sinned and God forgave David but his son, who was the unborn in the womb of Bathsheba died, the guilt was revisited on another generation because of the sin of the father. Hence, why does the guilt remain on the later generations even though the fathers were forgiven?
Adam and Eve sinned too and even though they were forgiven, the guilt remained, and their offspring still pay for their errors through death.

Those who remain guilty are those who have not been justified. I think you have misunderstood the verse.

@NigelJ, have added other important contexts to the question which supports the interpretation that even in forgiveness, later generations pay for the error or sin.

This question is similar to: About Exodus 20:3-5. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

Given that Exodus 34:7 is a parallel of Exodus 20:3-5, the same matter is being asked about and has 3 answers.

As someone who is prone to a touch of numeric dyslexia (transposing figures), I recognised the two later references to Exodus 7:34 to actually being intended for 34:7! Sympathies!
Well Exodus 34:7 has two significant points that help answer your question. First, his mercy and forgiveness is unto thousands who love him. This stands in contrast to iniquity being visited upon the third or the fourth generation of individuals who  hate him. There could hardly even be more than a hundred in that latter category.
Second, that text needs to be read in conjunction with the initial rendition of that (the second of the 'Ten Commandments'). It reads:

"Thou shalt not bow down thyself to them, nor serve them: for I the
Lord thy God am a jealous God, visiting the iniquity of the fathers
upon the children unto the third and fourth generation of them that
hate me; and shewing mercy unto thousands of them that love me,
and keep my commandments." Exodus 20:5-6 A.V.

This served to warn the Israelites (and us) of the grave responsibility fathers have towards their children, grand-children, and great-grandchildren. If a father hates the Lord God, the effects (consequences) of such hatred will surely cause offspring to suffer. But if a child, grand-child or great-grandchild did not hate the Lord, but loved the Lord and kept his commandments, that one would "transfer", as it were, into the category of the thousands who are blessed by God because they love him, and keep his commandments.
This part of the 'Ten Commandments' has provisos. Hating and disobeying God = iniquities adversely affecting three or four generations. Loving and obeying God = blessings for thousands.
EDIT: In view of the edit added to the question, and the comment below, note that about a year had passed before Nathan confronted him with his as-yet unrepented-of sin. When David repented, he was immediately told that “the Lord has taken away your sin. You are not going to die. But because by doing this you have made the enemies of the Lord show utter contempt …“ the child born became ill, dying 7 days later – 2 Samuel 12:15.
The law required that David’s adultery, and arranging for the death of the innocent husband, Uriah, called for the death penalty. Yet God was merciful to David in not causing him to die, for despite what had happened, David never hated the Lord. So, mercy was shown to him. However, all sin has consequences, often going down the generations. David had to suffer, publicly, God’s discipline. See verses 11-12. Indeed, “the sword did not depart from his house” (verse 10). This confirms my paragraph starting, “This served to warn…” Fathers have a huge responsibility, and David’s failure due to his lust and effective murder of Uriah meant David suffered for decades the bad, and public, rebellion of his other sons, Absalom, Amnon, and Adonijah, who all sinned themselves as men. The violent deaths of all three confirms their wicked rebellion. All Israel witnessed this. God is not mocked. He graciously forgives the repentant sinner, but that does not stop bad consequences from sinful choices, as “Whatever a man is sowing, that he will also reap.” Job 4:8; Galatians 6:7 & Hosea 8:7 – “They have sown the wind and reap the whirlwind.” We have been warned. That principles applies throughout the whole Bible, from Adam to today.

I beg to bring up the incident where David sinned and God forgave him but his son who was the unborn in the womb of Bathsheba died, the guilt was revisited on another generation because of the sins of the fathers.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany But David was still pardoned and justified. By nature, there was a consequence. By grace, there was pardon and the imputation of righteousness to faith.

Up-voted +1. They who 'love God and keep his commandments' are they that are the recipients of his grace ; who are penitent, pardoned, justified and snactified.

@NigelJ, Sure but the guilt remained in the case of Adam, in the case of the Amalekites for they attacked the Israelites in the wilderness but later paid for it when God ordered Saul to spare none.

@SoFewAgainstSoMany Adam was also justified by faith for when Cain departed he departed from 'the presence of the Lord' that is to say, from Adam's household, who had responded by faith to the promise made to the woman, calling her Eve, by faith.

@NigelJ, do does the guilt remain for later generations to receive a punishment for it even though the soul that transgressed is long dead and was forgiven?

@SoFewAgainstSoMany . I would say yes. But it is a matter of nature and of the first humanity. And of the guilt of sin in the flesh. But redemption, by the sacrifice of Christ, brings in a new humanity, a new birth, justification and grace. And a better hope, though the consequences of the old must be endured until the final redemption of resurrection and eternal glory - the full effects of sonship.

@NigelJ, I do agree with you, with Christ some initial curses were lifted such as the sins of the fathers being punished on the sons and so on and so forth, some curtains were also lifted, even the curtain of ignorance.

First the general statement, then the specific question about Bathsheba's first son.
The general statement does present a paradox: God forgives sins yet does not clear the guilt and even punishes future generations for it. The interpretation of this passage was particularly vexing to the Jews in exile, who were experiencing the consequences of their ancestors' guilt all too personally. So great was their distress that the prophet Ezekiel went to considerable length in correcting those who believed there could be no hope for the descendants of those who sinned:
Ezekiel 18:

2 what is the meaning of this proverb you recite in the land of
Israel:  “Parents eat sour grapes,
but the children’s teeth are set on edge”?
3 As I live—oracle of the Lord God: I swear that none of you will ever
repeat this proverb in Israel. 4 For all life is mine: the life of the
parent is like the life of the child, both are mine. Only the one who
sins shall die!

Ezekiel went on to make it clear that if a person repented and did well, he/she would not be punished, even though his ancestor/s sinned grievously. This does not entirely resolve the paradox mentioned in the OP, but it supports the interpretation that God does clear the guilt of ancestral sin when the descendant/s act righteously.
Regarding David and Bathsheba's son the matter is more specific. This son would be a mamzer, a child of adultery. Even though God might forgive his parents, the consequences of their sin could not be erased in this particular case.
Deuteronomy 23:2:

A mamzer shall not enter into the congregation of the LORD;
even to his tenth generation shall he not enter into the congregation
of the LORD.

A mamzer could not enter the sanctuary, could not marry a wife who was born legitimately, could not build the temple, could not act as a judge or legislator, could succeed to the throne. Moreover, David had not only sinned against God, who could forgive the sin, but he had sinned against the nation and the kingship. So in this case, the Law had to be upheld and the way had to be cleared for a legitimate son, namely Solomon, to emerge.
This explanation does not entirely resolve the OP's question, for the child in question had not sinned. But it does shed light as to why the biblical author presents us with the facts of the case. It's interesting that this episode is omitted from the Book of Chronicles.

This is the answer I was looking for, Thank You.

Good points, but "God might forgive his parents" plural? I do not see anywhere in scripture that Bathsheba sinned. After David violated her marital status, she is not even named (until the time of Solomon.) But several times David's sin is stressed, and it is his sin against her innocent husband that is stated. Uriah seems to get overlooked in the (mainly) male preoccupation with Bathsheba. A recent series of sermons I heard on this showed such distasteful repetitious naming of Bathsheba (as if she had deliberately tried to seduce David). David sinned grossly. But +1

The question

In Exodus 34:7, God says He is abounding in goodness and mercy and forgives iniquity and transgression but he doesn't clear the guilt, what does this mean?

The answer
This is a misunderstanding of the text. This is clearer if we compare the NKJV translation with the NIV translation:
Exodus 34:7 NKJV

5 Now the Lord descended in the cloud and stood with him there, and proclaimed the name of the Lord. 6 And the Lord passed before him and proclaimed, “The Lord, the Lord God, merciful and gracious, longsuffering, and abounding in goodness and truth, 7 keeping mercy for thousands, forgiving iniquity and transgression and sin, by no means clearing the guilty, visiting the iniquity of the fathers upon the children and the children’s children to the third and the fourth generation.”

Exodus 34:5-7, NIV

Then the Lord came down in the cloud and stood there with him and proclaimed his name, the Lord. 6 And he passed in front of Moses, proclaiming, “The Lord, the Lord, the compassionate and gracious God, slow to anger, abounding in love and faithfulness, 7 maintaining love to thousands, and forgiving wickedness, rebellion and sin. Yet he does not leave the guilty unpunished; he punishes the children and their children for the sin of the parents to the third and fourth generation.”

The important point to understand here is that this is a text about God's general character. The wider setting is the Law given at Mount Sinai, which now has to be repeated because of the idolatry of the golden calf. The quoted passage is God's recital of his character as he meets again with Moses. And that character is one of both grace and judgment.
The OP assumes that when we read "forgiving iniquity and transgression and sin, by no means clearing the guilty", we are to take that as a description of how God deals with a particular person. He forgives them, but doesn't take their guilt away. A kind of "half forgiveness", so to speak.
But that's not the meaning here. The NIV gives a clearer picture, which is that this is God's character in his overall dealings with humanity and throughout history. It's true that there is a mixture of grace and judgment, but this is not focussed on one person. It's a broad sweep. In simple terms God is saying, "I am a God of mercy to thousands of people. But I am also a God of judgment towards many people." We might say that this is a picture of a well-balanced God.
Israel herself certainly experienced this double picture of God. Even at this moment we see grace in the fact that God remained faithful to his covenant and didn't totally destroy Israel. Yet we also see judgment in that the result of Israel's disobedience was a refining of that generation through 40 years of wandering in the desert.

If the guilt doesn't remain, why does humanity still die as a consequence of the first sin even though Adam was forgiven?

Why did God not spare Bathsheba's son with David even though David repented and fasted?
